# organizing instance creation in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a project with many classes.there are GUI class JDBC for database acceess and defferent methods. there is a class called connect.java which is connecting to the databases and check if the username and password are correct.
connect.java  has two methods,connect() which is connectig to the database and check(String user,String password) which is retreiving username and password from the database and check if there correct.check method is getting these user name and password form the login form from login.java class.
there is another class called LOGIN.java this class contains login form which intend to call 
connect.java if everything is right the Home.java Appear right after the use is successfully logged in. there is another class called library which contains main method

what i was wondering is how do i organize all these classes so that at the first time when the application is loaded the login window appear,then after the use login the home page comes.some times i find myself created a kind of loop inside classes where one class "A" create an instance of class "B" after i realize that class "B" need data from class "A" then i create another instance of class "A" in "B" then these two classed keep calling each other
i would like to ask advice on how to organize my classes when i have class which are in charge of creating GUI and other classes which are managing databases connection and data retrieval may be network management.how do call these class in correct order?thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use design patterns like

1.DAO and DTO for managing your database functionality.

2.Singleton pattern for Instance managing.

Comment: You can also have a look on injection and Guice. It's quite an interesting way to manage instances in Java (https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/).